# Magento2.1.0 Checkout page Not redirecting to success or error page when order is made by Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net, magento2.1.0

I have upgraded to Magento2.1.0 and **when i make payment through Authorize.net the checkout page hangs with the Spinning Loader, it is not redirecting to Success or Error page**. Did anyone Came across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and found a ticket in Github here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4813

I am working on fixing this, too. Will update here any result.

**UPDATED**: 
So the root cause is the missing of `base_grand_total` column in `sales_invoice_grid` table. That will cause error when creating invoice (in authorize & capture transaction, or capturing a pre-auth transaction).
My issue was fixed after adding that column:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_invoice_grid ADD base_grand_total decimal(12,4) AFTER grand_total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your vendor/magento folder with fresh vendor/Magento setup if you have made changes in core files like contact module or other modules than issue occurred. and also

Also check with direct post method with live mode.